# Searching few rows with one variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

On website there is form with ONLY ONE input field to provide either first name, last name or both.
In database there is table User with fields: id, firstname, lastname.

How to write SQL query to select all users with only one variable from input field provided. It's MySQL DB.

```
function getUsers($userInfo){
    $sql = "
        ?????????????????
    ";
    return getResult($sql);
}
```

Comment: Information such as RDBMS, the sql you've tried, and what didn't work, would be helpful to add to this post.

Comment: try: SELECT FROM user WHERE user_name='..' OR user_last_name='..' OR (user_last_name='...' AND user_name='...');

Comment: @i-bob that ain't work when I type both first name and last name into input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER 
WHERE FIRST_NAME = '$userInfo' 
    OR LAST_NAME = '$userInfo' 
    OR CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME) = '$userInfo'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM user 
WHERE ( user_name = '..' OR user_last_name = '..' )     OR 
      ( CONCAT(user_last_name, ' ', user_name) = '..' ) OR
      ( CONCAT(user_name, ' ', user_last_name) = '..' ) OR
LIMIT 0, 1;
```